# Orthogonality Relations of functions that differ at a single point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Starting with the cos orthogonality relations, we have:
$$
\dfrac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}\cos(n\dfrac{\pi}{L}t)\cos(m\dfrac{\pi}{L}t)dt=
\begin{cases}
0,m\neq n;\\
1,m=n\neq0;\\
2,m=n=0;
\end{cases}
$$

Suppose we changed one of the cosines over $[-L,L]$ at a single point as follows:
$$
f(t)=
\begin{cases}
cos(n\dfrac{\pi}{L}t),t\neq0;\\
0,t=0;
\end{cases}
$$
Are we still able to deduce orthogonality when $m\neq n$ of:
$$ \dfrac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(t)\cos(m\dfrac{\pi}{L}t)dt$$

I think yes, as $f(t)$ is like $(\cos(n\dfrac{\pi}{L}t))$ at all but a single point, but just want to double check and ensure that there are no issues. my only reservation is that $\cos(nt)\cos(mt)=1$ at $t=0$, so should we have to make an adjustment to the integral for the single point?

Comment: A single point has measure zero so will not effect the value of the integral.

Comment: @epiliam, thanks for the reply (and good luck with your degree).